# Layout of magento admin module changes

Tags: magento2, module, adminhtml, grid-layout

i'm creating a module for magento admin and it has so many fields, but as seen in image attached, i want field of price 2 to be on next right to price 1 field. can you anyone please suggest the solution for this.

Thanks [image]